# Getting chrome console output using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I'm very new to both selenium and chrome console. what I'm trying to do is to get the output from chrome console, after typing a line of java script, and I just need the output, not the entire log.
the script I want to run is OptanonActiveGroups
and the results in red is what I'm trying to get

[image]

I have tried both `driver.execute_script("console.log('OptanonActiveGroups')")` and `console_output = driver.execute_script('return console.log("OptanonActiveGroups")')`, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that object is global and set you could just do:

```
optanonActiveGroups = driver.execute_script("return OptanonActiveGroups")
```